# PL/SQL using XMLELEMENT changes formatting

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I'm using PL/SQL with the XMLElement function that helps me formatting some VARCHAR columns into a XML format. My problem is, that XMLElement seems to convert the encoding into something that can't read special characters and therefore outputs the stored VARCHAR like this `'text&quot;text'`.

If I do the same query without XMLElement, I get the desired output as it appears to be stored, i.e. `'text"text'`.

Exemplary query that changes the encoding:

```
  SELECT XMLElement("element", T.COLUMN) 
  FROM TABLE T;
```

Exemplary query that returns the expected encoding:

```
  SELECT T.COLUMN
  FROM TABLE T;
```

I tried using CONVERT(T.COLUMN, 'UTF8') but the XMLElement function seems to process the input afterwards and therefore changes the encoding (that's my guess).

How do I prevent PL/SQL form changing the encoding respectively how can I convert it back?

- I'm using the Oracle SQL Developer

**Solution from comments:**

```
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(XMLElement("element", T.COLUMN).GetClobVal(), 1) FROM TABLE T;
```

Comment: Special characters `"`, `<`, `>` and `&` are escaped in XML - sometimes even mandatory. Actually in your example is not required, however looks like XMLElement escapes them in any case.

Comment: Maybe try `SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(XMLElement("element", T.COLUMN).GetClobVal(), 1) FROM TABLE T;`. But be aware, the result might be a invalid XML document.

Comment: You just need .getClobVal() at the end

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit that resolved my problem, thanks!